# Interview questions are off-topic. What about questions that I, as the interviewer, have?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

If I'm interviewing someone for a programming job and I have questions about how I'd best assess whether the candidate actually has a particular skill, would that be an on-topic questions?

An example I'd have in mind would be a question like

"I'm interviewing someone for an entry-level programming job and want to assess if they can produce *clean code* and use test-driven development. What would be a good way to check that?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [scope what is considered on-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is [the systems development life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) - methods and practices, requirements, architecture, design, testing, configuration management, build, release, deployment. Interviewing and hiring practices are not part of the systems development life cycle and such questions would be off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. "Development life cycle" is a great and clear scope delimiter. 

Now where to ask that question of mine... seems like career related programming stackexchanges never really took off unfortunately.